# Can anyone please explain to me how market cap works in some details in DeFi (ETH, BSC, Polygon)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan, uniswap, evm

Like trying to launch a coin on two chains with different liquidity but wanna keep price and market cap the same.

For example token same contract: on the polygon chain with 50k liquidity
On the ether chain 200k liquidity

Also how will the marketcap change over time when people begin trading.

Answer (score 0):

Market cap is dependenet on price and circulating supply.

current circulating supply of tokens * current price = market cap!

When the coin begins trading, market cap will change by people buying/selling the token and if you have a mint/burn mechanism (which affects cirulating supply) that wil also affect the market cap.

In terms of the smart contract aspect of keeping the same price and market cap with differen't liquidity I don't want to steer you in the wrong direction so someone else might be able to answer that one.